# scan from printer to pdf file via a network

Tags: fedora, scanner

OS.  Fedora 28  64 bit  gnome fully up dated
Printer Brother MFC-J6530DW
Fixed IP addresses XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WW2 for the printer
Fixed IP address for the Computer XXX/YYY.ZZZ.WW3 for the Computer
The printer printed from the Fedora machine with no problems.

Now I want to be able to put a document on the tray or multiple pages in the Document feeder and press the  "scan" "network" and the profile button and the documents will be scanned and a PDF copy put into the designated folder on the Fedora box. 
I have set up a folder /home/USER-NAME/Scanned_Docs
I have changed the permissions to give everyone access.
Setting the profile in the SCAN profile I put in a path 
//XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WW3/home/USER-NAME/Scanned_Docs but I get an error.

Error
Test Error
Server timeout, this message will appear when you can not connect to the server
Make sure that:
The Server address is correct.
Your Server is connected to the network
the machine is connected to the network
ECODE: 0x00002010, -32, 0xFFFFFDA7.

Yes the Server IP address is correct and I can see it on teh network from other machines.
I can ping the printer from the Fedora machine
I can ping the Fedora machine from other machines
Yes the printer is connected to the network,  I can print to the machine via the network from the fedora machine, USB and WIFI connections are NOT used.

I have tied the windows format to specify the path but nothing works.
I have installed Samba thinking that the printer may require a SMB protocol to work.  But I can not seem to get Samba to work.  I get a user listed when I run;
net usershare =L -v.

I have added share group, and a user to the group, set the path in Samba and set the samba conf as per the Serverworld for fedora 28 Samba scan to file all users  set passwords etc.

Have a friend h=who has a HP Officejet 8710 who wants to do teh saem but he is running Fedora 29.

Comment: The directory `/home/USER-NAME` is world writable and executable as well as `/home/USER-NAME/Scanned_Docs`? What transfer is being used? `ftp`? How is that setup? I do something similar from a Sharp Copier to an Archlinux server using `vsftp`. If what you are doing did work in the past and then stopped working, make sure Fedora didn't update the defaults for `pambase` now requiring each service to have a pam policy (e.g.a separate `/etc/pam.d/ftp`) rather than the older default.

Comment: Yes the /home/USER-NAmE and .home/USer-NAME/Scanned_Docs  directories are writable and executable by anyone.   I have never has this working where I can select the  Scan to file profile on the printer push "scan" and a scanned copy in PDF format ends up in the selected directory   eg /home/USER_NAME? Scanned_Docs.    I have done it before only only a windows computer not from a linux based machine.  I have done away with windows so I need to ge this scan to a file function working.

Comment: Have you tried the [Linux scanner driver from Brother](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj6530dw_us_eu_as) or [Brother Linux or Unix support](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/52188/~/linux-or-unix-support)? See [PDF Studio Knowledge Base](https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/install-printer-driver-on-linux/)

Comment: Yes I have done that.I am currently awaitinhg a 2nd response for Brother Linux or Unix Support. Just to be 100% clear  I can scan a document using Simplescan or XSane where thee app are controlled from the computer.

Comment: Yes I have done that.I am currently awaiting a 2nd response for Brother Linux or Unix Support. Just to be 100% clear  I can scan a document using Simplescan or XSane where thee app are controlled from the computer.     What I am trying to do is place a document on the scanner, select scan to file on the printer/scanner, select the profile and then scan and find a PDF copy in a nominated shared folder on a nominated computer.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this may be a little too late, but I was encountering what I thought were permission issues with getting my brother MFC-L2750DW to connect to a samba share on Debian Buster with Armbian Linux. It turns out that the network path MY printer wants isn't the ACTUAL linux folder path.

My printer worked with a "Network Folder Path" in this format - `\\your.ip.address.here\samba_share_name_not_samba_shared_folder_path`.

In my case, `samba_share_name_not_samba_shared_folder_path` is the name of the share I created in `smb.conf`, and not the actual folder path.

This is my entry for my share at the bottom of `smb.conf`, which the printer referenced as `\\my.samba.ip.address\network_scans`:

```
[network_scans]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /media/bitsync/personal/Network_Scans
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
```

Notice the name of the share (the top line of the declaration) is not the same as the path specified in the share.

This is different behavior compared to the path you have to enter for a Windows 10 share. With a Windows 10 share, you enter the full folder path (with permissions of course) to "Network Folder Path" in the brother setup.

I hope this can still help you, or others that may stumble upon this in the future.